# Slight Issue with usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

Having a slight issue getting my array to sory by `Distance` properly.  I though that using `usort` would do the trick, but I am apparently mistaken?

## usort

```
usort($return, function($a, $b){
    $t1 = $a['Distance'];
    $t2 = $b['Distance'];
    return $t1 - $t2;
});
```

`$return` produces:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06096
        [Distance] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06096
        [Distance] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06026
        [Distance] => 3.16
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06080
        [Distance] => 4.14
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06080
        [Distance] => 4.14
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06078
        [Distance] => 4.14
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06064
        [Distance] => 3.6
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06028
        [Distance] => 3.6
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06028
        [Distance] => 3.6
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06006
        [Distance] => 4.83
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06095
        [Distance] => 4.83
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06095
        [Distance] => 4.83
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [ZipCode] => 06006
        [Distance] => 4.83
    )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you are using `strtotime` on distances?

This should work:

```
usort($return, function($a, $b){
    return $a['Distance'] - $b['Distance'];
});
```

**Edit:**

Ok I see what the problem is, as written in [the doc](http://php.net/usort):

> Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

So the solution is to make sure the comparison function always returns an integer:

```
usort($return, function($a, $b){
    $t1 = $a['Distance'];
    $t2 = $b['Distance'];
    if ($t1 == $t2) return 0;
    return $t1 < $t2 ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: @o7thWebDesign, it's probably a different issue then, I've just tried this code and it should work. Could you post your complete code including the data?

Comment: I can't give you data.  It's the CSV dump from the USPS that I imported into MySQL.   And I gave you an example of the return data above.  The full code simply returns the array above completely unsorted.  Adding in the usort orders it to an extent... just not fully:   http://ctauto.o7th.com/assets/temp.php

Comment: @o7thWebDesign, ok I see what the problem is, I've updated my answer.